# Text with binary code

Tags: binary

The binary code for HELLO is 0100100001000101010011000100110001001111** but I can't found how to convert for example A in binary code.

How can I convert it and make a word like WORLD because I don't see free spaces in the binary code for HELLO?

For example *WORLD*, what is *W*, what is *O*, what is *R* ....

Should I add something between the different codes (for example: if W is 1010101, O - 000101, R - 1010111, L - 100001, D - 111111 Is it **1010101***000101***1010111***100001***111111** WORLD? )

Comment: And why i have -1? Reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary representation of a string is entirely dependent on its [encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). If you want to use the simple [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) case (one byte per character), then all you need to do is look up the hex code for the character you care about, 0x41 for 'A' for instance. From this point, converting it to a binary sequence is trivial. It's important to note that things like [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) comes into play with the actual binary representation.

For an encoding such as UTF-8, UNICODE, or a multi-byte encoding, the process is less straight forward and you'd be better off using a library function to get the binary representation.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) to get the decimal number for a letter.

For example:

O = 79 -> 1001111

P = 80 -> 1010000

S = 83 -> 1010011

Just use your calculator to convert decimal number to binary, so:

OPS = 100111110100001010011

Something like this.

Hope it helps